# compute $\int_0^1\sqrt{x(1-x)}dx$.

Tags: real-analysis, integration

My sister has a following integral to compute
$$\int_0^1\sqrt{x(1-x)}dx.$$

I know how to compute it : doing the substitution $x=\sin^2(u)$ yields
$$\int_0^{\pi/2}2\sin(x)^2\cos^2(x)dx=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2(2x)dx=\frac{1}{4}\int_0^{\pi/2}(1-\cos(4x))dx=\frac{\pi}{8}.$$

So I know how to do it. However, my sister is in high school, and they never saw substitution, so it's impossible that it's what her teacher expect. Is there an other way to compute it with more elementary tools ? I don't see it...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/170284/42969

Comment: A possible method to find such a method would be to compute the primitive using any method you know, then derive this primitive until you obtain the original function. Then, by doing the steps backward, you will have found a method that does allow to compute the integral, without using integration by substitution. You could also use integration by parts.

Answer (score 24):

Notice that $$x(1-x)=\frac14-\left(x-\frac12\right)^2.$$
Sketch the curve
$$y=\sqrt{\frac14-\left(x-\frac12\right)^2},$$
then we find that it is the top half of a circle of radius $\frac12$ centered at the point $(1/2,0)$. By the geometric meaning of the definite integrals, we have
$$ \int_0^1\sqrt{x(1-x)} \,dx=\frac12\cdot (\text{Area of the circle})=\frac12\cdot\pi\cdot\left(\frac12\right)^2=\frac\pi8.$$

Sorry for my poor English. I've added a picture. I hope that it will be much more helpful.

[image: Picture]

Comment: +1:  perhaps worth saying "Sketch the curve: it is the top half of a circle radius $\frac12$ centred at $(\frac12,0)$" if you are at high school

Comment: @Henry Thanks for your comments! I've changed some of my words. I'm not good at describing the pictures in my head using English. If you or any other people think that it will be better after editting some more words, please feel free to do so. :)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3865109/42969